# Mapping of a horizontal line $y = c$ by $w = \frac{1}{z}$ onto which region?

Tags: complex-analysis, mobius-transformation

I was trying to solve this problem ,

so $y = c$. Suppose for ease let us take $c > 0$.

so $w = \frac{1}{z} = \frac{1}{x + iy} = \frac{x - iy}{x^2 + y^2} = \frac{x - ic}{x^2 + c^2} =  \frac{x}{x^2 + c^2} - i( \frac{c}{x^2 + c^2})$.

Now as $w = u + iv$,

comparing we get $u = \frac{x}{x^2 + c^2}$ and $v = \frac{-c}{x^2 + c^2}$ and also $u^2 + v^2 = \frac{1}{x^2 + c^2} \leq \frac{1}{c^2}$ and I think this is a disc centered at $0$ and of maximum radius of $\frac{1}{c}$.

Next I am thinking that since $v = \frac{-c}{x^2 + c^2}$  and $c > 0$ that would imply that $v$ is always negative but now if this sis the case then what I have got the region as disc will be wrong as it contains some positive $v$  also the upper part of the disc and hence now I am getting the region as semicircular disc with arc in the negative $v$ axis.

Is this correct?.if not where I am making mistake.
Any help is great.

Comment: are all circles centered at the origin?

Comment: as the equation in $uv$ plane is $(u-0)^2 + (v-0)^2 = \frac{1}{x^2 +c^2}$,with radius varying as $x$ varies,I think  all the circles are centered at  the origin@robjohn ?

Comment: Since $u$ and $v$ vary as $x$ varies, that equation is not going to be very useful in telling you what the curve in the $u,v$ plane is.

Comment: actually if we consider a circle $x^2 + y^2  = 1$,here also $x,y $ varies and hence they could plot a circle. here we get a case where the radius is varying implying a disc! @robjohn

Comment: How about the above comment,like any other instance where the above kind of thing does not work.@robjohn

Comment: I am not sure to what you are referring. If the shape is a circle and you find the proper center, the radius is always constant. If you read the section of the article I linked in my answer, you will see that the map $z\mapsto\frac1z$ sends circles and lines to circles and lines in the complex plane.

Comment: Since $u$ and $v$ vary as $x$ varies, that equation is not going to be very useful in telling you what the curve in the $u,v$ plane is.? -- I want to explore this thought @robjohn

Comment: The equation you have written, $(u-0)^2 + (v-0)^2 = \frac{1}{x^2 +c^2}$, is not very useful in telling what the curve is. $u^2+\left(v+\frac1{2c}\right)^2=\frac1{4c^2}$ is more useful.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Hint:** Consider the absolute value of $w+\frac i{2c}$.

Also look at [Inversive Geometry](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Inversive_geometry#Reciprocation).

Comment: Thanks but how does that help?

Comment: What did you get for the absolute value? How does it vary for different points on the $x,y$ line?

Comment: I was calculating the absolute value and it involves terms of $x$ and since $x$ is varying so the absolute value also varies?

Comment: $\frac{x-ic}{x^2+c^2}+\frac{i}{2c}=\frac{2cx+i(x^2-c^2)}{2c(x^2+c^2)}$ The absolute value should be $\frac1{2c}$.

Comment: Yes I should have been careful about that the $x$ may too have been cancelled out leaving a constant term.and hence we would get a circle centered at $\frac{-i}{2c}$ and radius $\frac{1}{2c}$.

Comment: Indeed! This is hopefully how the hint is helpful.